# How to divide solutions of system of ODE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

If I have the following system of ODEs:
\begin{align}
F'_1=aF_1+bF_2 \nonumber\\
F'_2=-bF_1+cF_2 \nonumber
\end{align}for which I know the solutions of $F_1$ and $F_2$ as sums of exponential of eigenvalues. My question is can I find an ODE for $z=\dfrac{F_1}{F_2}$ . I want this so that I can find the following integral $$\int_{t_0}^t\dfrac{F_1(s)}{F_2(s)}ds$$ explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $F_2 \neq 0$, you can use the quotient rule to get the following (non-linear) ODE for $F_1/F_2$:

$$\left(\dfrac{F_1}{F_2}\right)' = \dfrac{F_1'F_2 - F_1F_2'}{F_2^2}=\dfrac{(aF_1 + bF_2)F_2 - F_1(-bF_1 + cF_2)}{F_2^2}$$
$$
=\dfrac{bF_1^2 + (a - c)F_1F_2 + bF_2^2}{F_2^2}
$$
$$
= b\left(\dfrac{F_1}{F_2}\right)^2 + (a-c)\dfrac{F_1}{F_2} + b
$$

If you just want to find the value of that integral, you can use the solutions you know from the system to (maybe) calculate it directly. E.g. the integral will be something like

$$
\int_{t_0}^t \frac{c_1 a e^{\lambda_1 t} + c_2 b e^{\lambda_2 t}}{c_1 c e^{\lambda_1 t} + c_2 d e^{\lambda_2 t}} \,dt
$$

for some (different) constants $c_1,c_2,a,b,c,d$. You may not be able to explicitly find an (elementary) anti-derivative, but you will still be able to evaluate it numerically and perhaps study other aspects of its behavior.

Comment: yes my integral looks like the one you have there, but can that integral be found explicitly?

Comment: in general, no I don't think you can always find an explicit (elementary) anti-derivative; you might only get numerical solutions or be able to study behavior qualitatively. But for some constants (i.e. the right $a,b,c,d$) you may be able to solve, or if you're looking at a *particular* solution (so that $c_1$, c_2$ are fixed and "helpful"). Give me a minute to play with this system and see if anything helpful occurs w/ these coefficients (in particular, I can see that it could have complex eigenvalues)

Comment: Yeah, nothing pops out at me. this system allows a wide variety of coefficients; looking at original $a,b,c$, the eigenvalues are complex if $(a-c)^2 < 4b^2$, real otherwise, they can be distinct, they can be repeated, etc.